# When receiving [RST, ACK] flags, what values should be assigned for SEQ and ACK?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, pcap, computer-forensics

The below screenshot shows the relevant packets I am analysing, which are independent from the rest of the network traffic.

I know that this is malformed network traffic, however I am confused as to why the correct values should be [RST,ACK] Seq = 1 Ack = 1 ... in oppose to the values seen in the screen shot for packet 8.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated, as most of the online documentation and explanations I have read, have not given a concrete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 793, page 37:

In the SYN-State (The sender sent a segment with SYN flag, packet 7), The received RST segment (packet 8) is acceptable if the ACK field acknowledges the SYN.

So, packet 8 is malformed and not acceptable for sender of SYN segment, because ACK field is here 0 (relative) instead of 1.